# Marshalling issue while using rmi

Tags: java, exception, marshalling, rmi, remoteexception

i m trying to use rmi. The code below is the code that i m using it to bind.

```
    @Override
    public void init(String serviceName) throws RemoteException {
    /*if(System.getSecurityManager() == null){
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    }*/
    try {
        String host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        String url = "rmi://"+ host + "/"+ serviceName;
        //String url = "//localhost/" + serviceName;
        Naming.rebind(url,this);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

no matter which url i use i m getting the exception below. It never finds the class to marshall. Can someone help me about this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ceng443.hw3.base.SocialNetworkServer
```

Comment: How is the service class defined? Are you extending UnicastRemoteObject?

Comment: In which line does the exception occur?

Answer (score 0):

You need a securitymanager in order to download any code using RMI, but you have it commented out in the fragment you posted. Can you try uncommenting your securitymanager setup?

Comment: i think my problem is not about the solution you sad. If it was then i whould get security exceptions. In addition to this i was just trying to creat RMI not to use it from client side and download st.